# Как реализовать websocket для уведомления на стороне юзера?

Tags: python, angular2, websocket

Фронт написал на Angular2, бекэнд на Django. Как можно реализовать websocket для связи фронта и бэка для реализации механизма уведомлений? 
Интересует именно сторона бэка, какие либы есть готовы и если можно то готовые решения или пример кода.
Сам просто на стороне бэка ни разу websocket не реализовывал.

Comment: Если речь про пуш уведомления то можно не морочится и воспользоваться сторонними сервисами вроде sendpuls

Comment: Не имею опыта связки websocket и Django, но слышал что там есть какие-то проблемы, если бы передо мной стояла такая задача, скорее я бы смотрел в сторону дополнительного микро-сервиса с socketIO например

Comment: [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels)